# Firebase only allow write for logged in user

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm setting up a new project in Vue JS. I'm building a blog, with a Firebase integration. The idea is that any logged in user is able to create blog posts which gets saved to the Firebase real-time database under: `https://xxx.firebaseio.com/blogs.json`, each blog has a unique firebase ID.

The issue I'm having, is that if there are multiple users creating blog posts, the traditional Firebase rules dictate that for the logged in user, the blog posts will be created under **that** user, and if another user is logged in, their blogs posts will appear under their user.

This is fine, however it means when I'm trying to do a `v-for` over my blog posts, I have two objects, each for the user, with potentially multiple blog objects in each one with no way of taking these out.

Below is my current rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "blogs": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false,
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to create all the blog posts for a logged in user, and have the posts created under `blogs` rather than the user ID: `$uid`, how can I achieve this?

Currently, this is the output I get with my current rules listed about:

```
{
    "PvWsi3t9mFZza5gXP8qNQaCktDN2": {
      "-LrZ87XS02DanBTybhij": {
        "body": "<p><strong>test</strong></p>",
        "creation": "",
        "slug": "test",
        "title": "My very first blog post"
      },
      "-LrZ8KjsJyGT1YFsIJ3G": {
        "body": "<p><strong>jjj</strong></p>",
        "creation": "2019-10-19",
        "slug": "test-2",
        "title": "Second post"
      }
    },
    "yLLOq9jC5odefHBENkO3r2ztNzZ2": {
      "-LrZ8ZRhLVEylBFaGcnq": {
        "body": "<p>content here</p>",
        "creation": "2019-10-04",
        "slug": "test-two",
        "title": "My very first blog post - ryan"
      }
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my Firebase ref which adds a blog post:

```
firebase.database().ref('blogs/' + this.$store.state.user.uid).push(this.post).then(() => {
         console.log('success')
      }).catch((err) => {
         console.log('error', err)
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rules such as (untested)

```
"rules": {
    "blogs": {
        ".read": true,
        "$blogId": {
            ".write": "(!data.exists() || data.child('author').val() == auth.uid)
                    && (newData.child('author').val() == auth.uid || !newData.exists())"
        }
    }
}
```

you can use a flat structure for your blogs, by adding an `author` field in them and forcing it to be the UID of the creator.

First ".write" line means "it's a new blog or it's YOUR blog".

Second line means "it is now YOUR blog or it is deleted".

Your code should be something like

```
const postWithAuthor = this.post;
postWithAuthor.author = this.$store.state.user.uid;
firebase.database().ref('blogs').push(postWithAuthor).then(() => {
    console.log('success');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```

You are concerned that, by making the UIDs publicly known, anyone can use a fake UID and write to your database. It's like saying people shouldn't know you're "RyanHolton", because they could make posts and label them as yours.

In your rules, `newData.child('author').val() == auth.uid` ensures that if someone says they're X, they're also authenticated as X. People would indeed be able to write to your database, but they'd have to put their real UID for "author".

If you want to allow only SOME people to write, you should add their UIDs in your database, possibly in the "admins" path, and add

```
&& root.child('admins/'+auth.uid).exists()
```

to your ".write" rules.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: `Error saving rules - Line 6: Invalid == expression: left operand is not a number, boolean, string, null.
` is the error I get when trying to publish the new rules, also I updated `('author)` as there's a syntax error here.

Comment: The logged in user to the dashboard will have a `$uid`

Comment: Updated to:

```
".write": "(!data.exists() || data.child('author').val() == auth.uid) && (newData.child('author').val() == auth.uid || !newData.exists())"
```
However, I get permission denied, updated my original question with how I'm creating a post

Comment: @RyanHolton Oops :) I fixed the rules sample. I see you're adding `this.$store.state.user.uid` to the path. With my rules, you shouldn't.

Comment: this is working now! Thanks! The only issue I'd have now though is with the `postWithAuthor.author` being saved into the Firebase realtime database, ideally I wouldn't want to store a user's `uid` in the database, I'd want to replace it with something different before it gets saved, because if someone knew the `uid` of a user, they'd be able to write to the database?

Comment: @RyanHolton Check my update on the answer. That'd be too long for a comment.

Comment: It is possible to create a database structure that would validate the UIDs, without making them publicly readable. If you have 2 authors and add a public game "guess who wrote this blog", people could use the UIDs to cheat. But you're not making this game, are you? :D